# (WiX) - Auto-generate GUID with pre-build event (heat.exe)

Tags: xml, wix, guid, wix3.5, wix3

i've made a pre-build event for my directorys/files. now its creating the source.wxs fine, but there are only 'GUID="*"', so now i get compiler error because it is not mapped on ProgrammFilesFolder, but every component needs an unique GUID:

```
Path" %SystemDrive%\st /MIR
"%WIX%\bin\heat.exe" dir %SystemDrive%\st -dr INSTALLDIRECTORYFOLDER -cg    SourceComponentGroup -var var.SourcePath -ag -out "$(SolutionDir).\Setup\source.wxs"
```

result:

```
<Component Id="cmp97CD2699CFD0E466AE00E9EE0BC75B3D" Directory="dirE9158D60656EC6CD461378A2C8EDC064" Guid="*">
     <File Id="filD6533D5A559BC86E4704F435FEEE2A5A" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourcePath)\test1.txt" />
</Component>
```

Are there any parameters i can change to get the desired effect? i couldnt find any documentation about the parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without knowing the exact compiler error I can't say whether this will fix it, but to get heat to generate the guids for you, you need is the `-gg` switch rather than `-ag`. FYI the commandline options can be found [here](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/heat.htm).

Comment: solved the Problem +1!
and thanks for the link also, couldn't find this